# Dooekeeper authorize loses params after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, access-token, doorkeeper

I am using doorkeeper and devise, clicking the following link

```
localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?client_id=37ba9a06dd5e09c9be0332d5d977bcaaa64bae1f585f4aa898d1a3c5c34a2098&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001&scope=info&response_type=token
```

cause me to  get the token if i am already logged in, but if i am not logged in i got redirceted to users/sign_in (devise view) as usual, and after login it sends me to

```
   localhost:3000/oauth/authorize
```

without any params.
I wont be able to get the token and doorkeeper displays the following error: The authorization server does not support this response type caused by the missing of response_type params.
Any idea about what i need to check?

Answer (score 1):

My fault i was using a bugged version of devise(3.2.1) that does not keep the querystring when you get redirected to the sign in page so if you url would be foo.com?bar=a after signing in you wuld be redirected only to foo.com.
Solved updating the gem to 3.2.2
Here is the documentation about it https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.2/CHANGELOG.md